# PHP SHA3 functionality

Tags: php, hash, sha-3

Is there a framework or function that allows me to use SHA3-512?
I don't want a extension like [Strawbrary](https://github.com/strawbrary/php-sha3)

Comment: Is that level of hashing *really necessary*?

Comment: @RobW SHA is a hashing algorithm, not encryption, and necessity of security depends on the task.

Comment: Something in pure PHP sounds like it would be pretty slow. Did you really need SHA3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**It's possible.**

Maybe too late, but I've worked on a `pure-PHP` implementation [here](https://notabug.org/desktopd/php-sha3-streamable):

- SHA3-224/256/384/512
- SHAKE128/256 (arbitrary output size)
- `LGPL 3+`
- Works in `PHP 5.2+` (considerably slower on older `PHP`)
- No extensions required.
- Moderately well tested.
- Based on the (public domain) reference implementation in `C`.
- Arbitrary input size.

It is a simple and fast implementation in `PHP` (which means **far slower than C**). Since this is purely "CPU-bound", `PHP 7.0` runs 4x faster than `PHP 5.6`. (55kB/s here)

Fine with a small input. Correctly handles a huge input, just hogs `CPU` for minutes.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think you should watch out with implementing this yourselves for security reasons. Correctly implementing a hashing algorithm is just as important as designing an algorithm. Also consider that the reference implementation is not necessarily secure: they don't often consider timing attacks. Anyway, PHP is not the language to implement these cryptographic primitives.

Answer (score 18):

Yes sure simply you can use hash function in php

```
<?php
echo hash('sha3-512' , 'String you want to hash');
```

Comment: `sha3-512` does not exist in PHP.  https://3v4l.org/kR8UJ  It seems only HHVM has it.

Comment: @Brad running `hash_algos()` on php7.2 shows that it 'sha3-384' does indeed exist

Comment: sha3-512 is available in php 7.1.0+

Answer (score 7):

For those coming to this later (after this post) PHP 7.1.0 has support for SHA3-512.

Per the PHP Manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) the **hash_algos()** function will output your system's available hash algorithms. The following code will output your system's available hash algorithms:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r (hash_algos());
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

My output looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => md2
    [1] => md4
    [2] => md5
    ...
)
```

Comment: Please don't post links as answer, but explain the content of the link. What if the page is moved and someone is looking for that help ?

Comment: Thank you for the style guideline. I have updated my answer to address them, and I'll adhere to it going forward.

Comment: Thanks...please upvote this answer for the future developer that will visit this page.

Answer (score -5):

PHP 5.3.2 added SHA-256 and SHA-512 to the crypt() function. This might be somewhat similar to what your looking for

https://www.php.net/crypt

Comment: Actually `password_hash()` is more secured than `crypt()`. I use password_hash with a strong salt to generate strong SHA-256 hashes.

Comment: Basit Saeed, why? There's no reason to think so.

Comment: @Basit-saeed - Your both right. password_hash() is more secure than crypt() but password_hash() is also a wrapper for crypt().