# What's wrong with my implementation of HMAC in PHP?

Tags: php, cryptography

I'm trying to implement a generic HMAC function in PHP. I'm following [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) and the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), but I cannot get my function to match the sample outputs. What am I doing wrong?

```php
function myHmac(string $data, string $key, callable $algoFn, int $algoBlockSizeInBytes): string
  {
    if (strlen($key) > $algoBlockSizeInBytes)
    {
      $key = $algoFn($key); // keys longer than blocksize are shortened
    }

    if (strlen($key) < $algoBlockSizeInBytes)
    {
      $key = $key . str_repeat(0x00, $algoBlockSizeInBytes - strlen($key)); // keys shorter than blocksize are zero-padded
    }

    $outerKeyPad = str_repeat(0x5c, $algoBlockSizeInBytes) ^ $key;
    $innerKeyPad = str_repeat(0x36, $algoBlockSizeInBytes) ^ $key;

    return bin2hex($algoFn($outerKeyPad . $algoFn($innerKeyPad . $data)));
  }

$md5Fn = function ($str) { return md5($str, true); };

echo 'my output: ' . myHmac("", "", $md5Fn, 64) . "\n";
echo 'correct output: ' . hash_hmac('md5', "", "") . "\n";
```

Comment: Trying to implement your own HMAC for one

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I know I'm not supposed to roll my own crypto. I'm trying to learn. Also, php doesn't support HMAC for SHA3, which I need.

Comment: PHP supports whatever is in [`hash_algos()`](http://php.net/hash-algos) which is system dependent for some algorithms, others are natively supported by PHP. sha384 should typically be in there.

Comment: FWIW, the XOR operator `^` is bitwise. You're performing bitwise operations on a string, which casts the operands to an integers. You're assuming the result is string. This probably accounts for a huge chunk of your mistakes here. Try debugging your code a bit more.

Comment: @Sherif: [the doc says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php): `If both operands for the &, | and ^ operators are strings, then the operation will be performed on the ASCII values of the characters that make up the strings and the result will be a string.` Sounds like that's exactly what I want, right?

Comment: I don't know. This was more of a casual observation since I tend to see a lot of people making mistakes with that in PHP. I didn't actually review your code to try and figure out what you wanted.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/q/17368899/3885509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You invoke `string_repeat()` with an integer instead of the string to be repeated. So integer to string conversion applies. This means that currently you get something like `0x36` -> `'54'` -> `'54545454...5454'` (`'54'` repeated 64 times) and so on. Use `chr(0x36)` to get the actual byte.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks.